# How to combine general solutions of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By Solving the following differential equation

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= \sqrt{y}\cos^2{\sqrt{y}}$$

I manage to obtain three solutions:

$$y=0, y=\left( n\pi + \frac{\pi}{2} \right)^2 , 2 \tan{\sqrt{y}} = x+C$$

where $n \geq 0, n \in \mathbb{N}$, $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

> Question: The solution given states that we may express the $3$ equations into 
>   $$y = \left( n\pi + \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x+C}{2} \right) \right)^2$$

How to express the above equation?

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that it is a lousy way of expressing it.

If you take $n=0$, then 
$$
y = \left(  \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x+C}{2} \right) \right)^2,
$$
which is exactly $y$ such that $2\tan\sqrt y=x+C$.

If you take $C\to\infty$, then 
$$\tag{1}
\lim_{C\to\infty} \left( n\pi + \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x+C}{2} \right) \right)^2
=\left(n\pi+\frac\pi2\right)^2.
$$
And if you allow $n=-1/2$ in $(1)$ above, you get $y=0$.